# Issue with postfinance module in oscommerce

Tags: oscommerce

I have integrated postfinance module for oscommerce. I have done everything mentioned in http://addons.oscommerce.com/info/6442 docs.When I tried to test it in 'test mode' ...after selecting the payment method it is redirecting to 'Order success' page with out showing option to enter postfinance card details....in the admin panel it shows that a purchase has been made and it is processing.

Comment: Do you have postfinance radio box at payment page of the checkout?

Comment: @Tim yes, after selecting "PostFinance (Card and E-Finance)", it will go to 'Order confirmation' page ..and if I confirm the order ...it goes directly to 'Order success' page...No error message is shown also the cart will become empty...

Comment: What is form action URL of your order confirmation page?

Comment: @Tim http://www.website.ch/checkout_process.php

Comment: at your checkout_confirmation.php find line if (isset($$payment->form_action_url)) { and echo $payment before it.

Comment: @Tim I have done what you have asked.. but nothing is printed...it is still  showing 'Your Order Has Been Processed!' page even after putting an exit;...I am not sure what is happening...

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/8058/discussion-between-tim-and-rajmohan)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At your checkout_confirmation.php please replace:

```
if ($$payment->code == 'paypal_ipn') {
```

with

```
if (isset($$payment->form_action_url)) {
```